# How to Password protect iOS app file?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, data-protection

I have an app where people could enter sensitive personal information. Is there a reasonable method to protect this from - even family access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very first launch of your App, ask a user to create a password, save it somewhere, then on each launch after the first, bring up a [modal view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) with a [`UITextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) and set the `secureTextEntry` property to `YES` (`myPasswordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;`) and do not dismiss the modal view until the password matches one that has been previously set.

[Apple Modal View Controllers Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)
[`UITextField` Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)
[`UITextInputTraits` Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html)

Comment: Thanks! That's straightforward and easy to implement. It's up to the user whether they want to invoke this and/or if they want to save/store their password.